# Lucene facet label index exception

Tags: java, lucene, faceted-search, facet

My Lucene facet index process starts to throw exception at the following spot at CompactLabelToOrdinal.java in Lucene facet,

```
int prevVal = collisionMap.addLabel(label, hash, ordinal);
if (prevVal != ordinal) {
    **throw new IllegalArgumentException("Label already exists: " + label + " prev ordinal " + prevVal);**
}
```

There are zero comments in the source code suggesting what could result in the error. Does anyone have a clue about this ?

Comment: Perhaps you should show how you're indexing your documents.